# Django intersection of non commited model objects and commited model objects

Tags: python, django

What I have is a list of model objects I haven't run `bulk_create` on:

```
objs = [Model(id=1, field=foo), Model(id=2, field=bar)]
```

What I'd like to do is intersect `objs` with `Model.objects.all()` and return only those objects which aren't already in the database (based on the `field` value).

For example, if my database was:

```
[Model(id=3, field=foo)]
```

Then the resulting `objs` should be:

```
objs = [Model(id=1, field=bar)]
```

Is something like this possible?

Edit:

So a bit of further explanation:

What I'm doing is I have an import command, that I'm trying to have an `--append` flag included.

Without the flag, I delete the tables, and start fresh.

With the flag, I want to bulk create a large number of objects (single creation is much slower - I've checked), and I don't want to have objects with the same field values but different ids.

I've already tried filtering out duplicates after insertion, but it's quite slow and I wanted to test this approach to see if it's faster.

The objects are read from CSV files, and it's faster to make a list of `Model`, and then `bulk_create`, as opposed to running `create` on each row.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Are you completely sure you don't want `objs=[Model(id=2, field=bar)]`?

Comment: It looks to me you are looking for a `get_or_create` function.

Comment: Added additional information explaining the problem. `get_or_create` would work, but I'm trying to `bulk_create` as it's much faster for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can probably best do this by first constructing a set of values the `field` column in the database has:

```
field_vals = set(Model.objects.values_list('field', flat=True).distinct())
```

and then we can perform a filtering like:

```
filtered_objs = [obj for obj in objs if obj.field not in field_vals]
```

By constructing a `set` first, we run a single query, construct a `set` in *O(n)* (with *n* the number of `Model`s in the database), and then filter in *O(m)* (with *m* the number of objects in `objs`). So the algorithm is *O(m+n)*.

---

Based on the question however, it looks like you could probably save the effort of constructing these objects in the first place. You can use Django's [**`get_or_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) function. And use it like:

```
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(field=foo)
```

with `obj` the objected (either fetched from the database, or created in the database), and `created` a `bool`ean that is `True`, if we had to create a new object.

Comment: While this is a valid answer I'd still be interested what the OP wants to achieve that makes this necessary. If he only wants to bulk create the filtered objects he didin't have to create too many in the first place :)

Comment: While this would work, `bulk_create`, is much faster for me than creating all objects on at a time.

Comment: @Darkstarone: an idea might also be to first obtain the set of `field`s, then construct new items based on that set, and thus never construct objects you do not need. Although constructing objects does not have a database cost (no query), it is still computationally expensive to create a new object (especially ones with a lot of magic).

Comment: That's a good idea too, I'll try both now and get back to you - thanks.